# How can I reindex a text file with ascii number data in a label?

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I'm refactoring code and have have created structures in my 'c' code that I need to relabel.  Ex:

```
static const unsigned char glyph_065[] = { 
    ... 
};
static const unsigned char glyph_066[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_067[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_065[] = { 
   ... 
};
static const unsigned char glyph_066[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_067[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_068[] = { ... };
... # then starting at line 300 say
{'A', 38, 20, glyph_065},
{'B', 38, 20, glyph_066},
{'C', 38, 20, glyph_067},
{'A', 38, 20, glyph_065},
{'B', 38, 20, glyph_066},
{'C', 38, 20, glyph_067},
{'D', 38, 20, glyph_068},
...
```

That I'd like to reindex.  Taking the above and making it:

```
static const unsigned char glyph_048[] = { 
  ... 
};
static const unsigned char glyph_049[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_050[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_051[] = {
  ... 
};
static const unsigned char glyph_052[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_053[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_054[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_055[] = { ... };
... # then starting at line # 300 say. 
{'0', 38, 20, glyph_048},
{'1', 38, 20, glyph_049},
{'2', 38, 20, glyph_050},
{'3', 38, 20, glyph_051},
{'4', 38, 20, glyph_052},
{'5', 38, 20, glyph_053},
{'6', 38, 20, glyph_054},
...
```

So the first field is the ascii representation of the number in the `glyph_` label.  I'd like to start at a number and just count up.  The literal character is just the ASCII represetation of the number so it will count past 9 as '7', '8', '9', ':', ';'  ...

My scripting knowledge is BASH, and doing this in BASH would be heinous. I'm sure this can be handled as two (2) `awk` one liners, or close to it at least.  Could someone get me started?

Comment: So you want to replace every `glyph_XX` to something starting from `48` (+1 every time) and the first field in the json string from a letter to a number starting from `0` (+1 every time)?

Comment: @fedorqui Exactly. The literal character '0' is just the ascii representation of the number `XXX` in the glyph name `glyph_XXX`.

Comment: You should have posted at least 10 lines of glyph values since it's not clear whether you'd want `{':', 38, 20, glyph_058}` or `{'10', 38, 20, glyph_058}` printed. I'm assuming the former in my answer.

Comment: @EdMorton Assuming that I'd count past '9' as ':', ';' ... is correct.  I added that to the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v s=48 '!f&&/^{/{c=0;f=1} /glyph_/{sub(/\047[^\047]+\047/,sprintf("\047%c\047",s+c)); sub(/glyph_[[:digit:]]+/,"glyph_"s+c); c++} 1' file
static const unsigned char glyph_48[] = {
    ...
};
static const unsigned char glyph_49[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_50[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_51[] = {
   ...
};
static const unsigned char glyph_52[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_53[] = { ... };
static const unsigned char glyph_54[] = { ... };
... # then starting at line 300 say
{'0', 38, 20, glyph_48},
{'1', 38, 20, glyph_49},
{'2', 38, 20, glyph_50},
{'3', 38, 20, glyph_51},
{'4', 38, 20, glyph_52},
{'5', 38, 20, glyph_53},
{'6', 38, 20, glyph_54},
...
```

Comment: Oooh the trick with `\047` to handle the single quote! I was struggling to get it work. Well done, +1!

Comment: With a much, much longer data set, the script doesn't restart the counting for lower part of the file.  I think I can take it from here though.  Thanks.

Comment: The script is unaffected by the length of the data. If it's not behaving as expected then there must be some specific values/layout in your input file that you haven't shown in your question, e.g. other lines that start with `{` or indenting that's different from what you showed.

Comment: @EdMorton For some reason the script keeps counting up: not worth debugging because it's still saved me a few hours.  Thanks.

Comment: The counter resets to zero the first time there's a `{` at the start of a line. You must have that earlier in your input file. If you can figure out what to key off in your input file I can help you write the code to test for that and reset the counter.

Answer (score 0):

This can work with static const not on one line:

```
num=48
count=0
while read line; do
  if [ $count -lt 300 ]; then
    l=${line/static const unsigned char glyph_.*[]/static const unsigned char glyph_$num[]}
  else
    if [ $count -eq 300 ]; then 
      num=48
    fi
    c=$[ count - 300 ]
    l=${line/[A-Z]/$c}
    l=${l/glyph_*}glyph_$num},
  fi
  echo "$l"
  num=$[ num + 1 ]
  count=$[ count + 1 ]
done <textfile.txt
```

Comment: The `static const` def isn't always on a single line.

Comment: @Jamie updated to work with static const not on one line. But in this case, how do you count the 300 lines?

Comment: Note that this will remove all indentation from your file and will have other side-effects too, some of which will only become apparent based on your input file contents and the files in the directory your executing it from. I also suspect it will print `10` instead of `:` for glyph #58. Shell is an environment from which to call tools. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. That's why it's so difficult to write robust shell code to manipulate text.

Comment: @StefanoF The line count is dynamic actually, but for the number of times I'll be running the script, I could just determine what the line number would be.

Comment: yeah @EdMorton but the original example file didn't have any indentation. Anyway with some quotes we can avoid the indentation problem. I'm very curious about the other side effects, can you please tell me something about it?

Comment: Quotes will not solve the indentation problems, but they would solve the inter-word space compaction and globbing problems. By not setting IFS correctly on the read, the shell will strip all leading and trailing white space from each line. By not invoking read in raw mode (-r) the shell will interpret backslashes. Unless you have a very specific purpose in mind you must always invoke read as `while IFS= read -r line` to get what would be the typical expected behavior of not messing with the line that's being read.

Comment: Wow, thank you @EdMorton, I was not aware about read raw mode and the IFS problem.

Comment: You're welcome. The core problem is that shell is just not designed for manipulating text so you have to jump through ALL sorts of hoops to do it robustly and often the problems aren't apparent until a year after you wrote it when you suddenly find some other input set run from some other directory or some other combination causes it to fail spectacularly. Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach - that's the job awk was invented to do and does best.

Comment: @EdMorton, I see your point. I started many years ago using bash cycles instead of awk for the very bad performances awk was having on very big files (and very slow computers). Maybe it's come the time to give it another try ;)

Comment: awk will VASTLY outperform shell scripts for text manipulation on large files on any computer. awk will usually outperform compiled C code too since it's optimized for text manipulation and that outweighs the overhead of being interpreted. There must have been problems in the way you wrote the awk code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a gawk script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
#

BEGIN { 
        new=NEW_INIT; 
        for (old=OLD_INIT; old<OLD_MAX; old++) {
          oldStr=sprintf("glyph_%03d",old);
          newStr=sprintf("glyph_%03d",new);
          array[oldStr]=newStr; 
          new++ ;
        }
}

{ 
        for (oldStr in array) {
                $0 = gensub(oldStr, array[oldStr], "g", $0);
        }
        print $0
}
```

And run it sending new numbers:

```
./script.gawk -v OLD_INIT=65 -v OLD_MAX=99 -v NEW_INIT=48 source
```